# php INSERT through Flash AS3 sometimes inserts weird Strings

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3

I haven't got clue if this is a normal issue or not but I have a small flash application that handles management for my company. It's a small company, so its not a big deal, its just a bunch of INSERTs, SELECTs, UPDATEs and other stuff to manage their clients, address, phone numbers, etc.

The flash (in AS3) sends the variables through a URLRequest to several php pages and the php handles the request to mySQL.

My problem is that, sometimes, instead of inserting the String I sent, it instead gets a weird string, made mostly, but not only, of numbers (and it happens like 1 column out of about 10 per INSERT, so its fairly common).

Is this a known issue? Could it be because of the encoding (I used UTF-8, which I believe is the one that we use here in portugal, due to special characters, like ã, à, á, etc)?

Thank you for your time.

Marco Fox.

Comment: Is it only happening to text/fields that has/have special characters in it?

Comment: Im not the one inserting data, so I really can't say, but I have noticed that I see absolutelly NO special characters in the database, thus my suspicions. I was using utf-8.bin , if that helps.

Comment: I would say the first thing to do then is establish an environment where you can replicate the problem the users are having. Without that it is difficult work out what could be wrong. You can then test the special characters yourself.

Comment: Aparently that was it, adding any special character on the database will make it a strange (and long) string. What is weirder is that when I "search" for the user that has that strange string in the Flash, it comes out allright (even with the speacial characters).. Only when viewed inside phpMyAdmin will it have that string. Well, at least its no big deal, I was starting to freak out thinking that some info could be lost. Thanks treffy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After connecting to the DB, try the following query "*SET CHARACTER SET utf8;*".

Make sure every PHP page are in utf-8.
To do that, open the file in Notepad++ and use the menu *Encoding -> Convert to UTF-8 without BOM*, or open the file in notepad and ask to *save as* and look at encoding dropdown bellow name (this will save the BOM, which is not good).
Some IDE have the ability to save in ANSI, UTF-8 and more, or have the conversion option.

In Flash, use *encodeURI()* in your URLLoader data if you are passing it by GET.

Hopes that this solves your problem (if it is, in fact, encoding issues).